# How to go to next computer in list of file does not exist when using shutil?

Tags: python

I have a program that goes through a list of computers and grabs a config file and saves it locally to my computer.  Currently, if the computer on the list does not have the config, the program will just continue on executing other functions on that same computer name.

I want to make it stop and say something such as "Filename does not exist on that computer." if the file does not exist.  Then instead of continue on with the other functions, I want it to stop and go to the next computer on the list for performing functions.

Any suggestions on how I can do this?

```
import os
import shutil
import fileinput
import re  # some of these used for other functions
import sys 


def direrror():
    print (" Error Here. ")


    # copy config from server/computer
def copyfrom(servername):   
    source = r'//' + servername + '/c$/remotedirectory/'
    dest = r"../mylocaldirectory"
    file = "filename.config"
    try:
         # here is where I want to stop and go to next computer in the list
         # if filename.config does not exist on remote computer
        shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(source, file), os.path.join(dest, file))


    except:
        direrror()

    otherfunctions(servername) #continue on to other functions if filename exists


# open list of servers/computers
os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
array = []
with open("serverlist.txt", "r") as f:
    for servername in f:

        copyfrom(servername.strip())
```

Comment: you'll need to check file exists at the remote computer path...I think something like os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dest,file))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dest,file)):
    try:
        ....
    except:
        ....
else:
    #doesn't exist...
    return "some_marker"
```

then in your for loop check if the returned value is equal the the marker and break your loop.